# String from label.text weird behaviour

Tags: c#, label

So I have a `Label` being initialized by a *WebService*. I want to see if that label *contains any commas*. The problem is, even if the label *has commas*, `Contains()` returns `false` and if I do a `Split()`, the array is only **1** element long, containing the *entire string*.

```
// text is "255,255,0,0"
string wat = myLabel.Text;
string[] wats = wat.Split(',');

// This IF never happens, for some reason
if (wat.Contains(","))
{
    anotherLabel.Text = wats[0] + " VS " + wats[1];
}
```

Why don't `Split()` and `Contains()` work? Can it be some kind of *diferent encode* in the string that comes from the label? If I do `wat = wat + ","`,  then `Contains()`returns `True`.

Comment: The result is false and i want to split that string to later use that numbers.

Comment: *even if the label got the comma when I use contains it gives false* then the label text don't have `,` in it for sure

Comment: `wats` is an array of `string`, the method `Split` returns the elements without the separator.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Is right, `wats.Contains(",")` is equivalent to `Array.Contains`, and the array after being split will not contain the comma. It should contain 4 elements though.

Comment: when do you call this code? add MessageBox.show(wat) to see if the variable contains the data

Comment: Can you check value of `wat` pls? I don't think it contains comma

Comment: Agree, let's have a (close) look at `wat`, e.g. `MessageBox.Show($"wat: [{wat}] encoded as {string.Join(" ", wat.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4")))}");`

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the `Contains` line, I think you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Unicode symbols are weird: what if we have, say `"255，255，0，0"` with full width commas? Instead of `"255,255,0,0"`.
`string wat = "255,255,0,0"; string[] wats = wat.Split(','); if (wat.Contains(",")) {MessageBox.Show("OK");}` doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: But even if i change the comma for a 2 for example if (wat.Contains("2") the result is still false so i think the problem is not the comma

Comment: Are you sure variable `wat` contains any text at all? You state it is being set by a web service, so problem might be related to asynchronously retrieved value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode symbols are often *weird*. Unicode has a lot of *commas*, e.g.

```
string wat = "255，255，0，0"; // Full range commas

bool hasComma = wat.Contains(','); // false
```

If `wat.Contains(',')` returns `false` then delimiters are not commas `,`. You can check it with `string` decoded:

```
string wat = myLabel.Text;

// Let's have a close look at wat: which characters (codes included) does it contain
MessageBox.Show(
  $"wat: [{wat}] encoded as {string.Join(" ", wat.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4")))}");
```

You should get

> wat: [255,255,0,0] encoded as 0032 0035 0035 **002c** 0032 0035 0035 **002c**
>   0030 **002c** 0030

if *not* check what character code(s) do you have instead of expected `002c`.

Comment: Thank you. I still have a problem but at least now i know what my problem is. I was testing my results using the labels to show my results. But using your code  Debug.WriteLine($"wat: [{wat}] encoded as {string.Join(" ", wat.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4")))}"); i know see that what the var wat was is not what i expected. [$(@cor)] encoded as 0024 0028 0040 0063 006f 0072 0029. Cor is the name of the value that comes from the server.

Answer (score -1):

The following line is always going to evaluate to false:

```
if (wats.Contains(","))
```

string.Split(',') will only return the values in between commas as you are specifying a comma as your delimiter. None of the items in the array will ever contain a comma.

If you want to check whether your label text contains commas simply do:

```
if (lblteste.Text.Contains(','))
```

Comment: Sorry mate was my mistake the line should have been wat,contains but the problem persists,

Comment: Right OK. Honestly just seems like the value of the label is not what you think it is. I.e it doesn't actually contain a comma. Try setting a breakpoint and see